# load all data from my field in db in my dropdownlist

Tags: php, jquery

hi everyone i am trying to get all the data from my db in my dropdownlist but now matter how i want it to load it all it only load the first 10 datas this is my code:

```
function getProdData(){
notifyClose();
$('#statusContent').show();
$('#preloaderContent').show();   
$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    async   : false, 
    data    :{
        productName : $('#searchBox').val(), 
        rows: rows,
        page: page
    },
    url     : baseUrl+'/admin/getproduct',
    error: function(req,error){ 
                notify('e',req.statusText);
            },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success : function(msg){    
        if(Object.keys(msg).length != 0){ 
            $('#discountedProduct option').remove();

            var optlst = "";
                optlst = "<option value=''>Select Product</option>";
            $.each(msg[0].row,function(i,e){
                optlst += "<option value='"+e.key+"'>"+e.productName+"</option>"; // in this part i want to put a code that will load all my data from my field in my db.

            });

            $('#discountedProduct').html(optlst);
        } 
    }
});
 $('#statusContent').fadeOut();
 $('#preloaderContent').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');   
}
```

is there a way that i could load all data in it ?

**EDIT:**

```
public function getproductAction(){
    $this->view->disable();
    $page               = $this->request->get('page');
    $rows               = $this->request->get('rows');
    $productName        = $this->request->get('productName');
    $productCode        = $this->request->get('productCode');
    $productPrice       = $this->request->get('productPrice');
    $productQuantity= $this->request->get('productQuantity');

    $url = $this->apiUrl."product/get?q=(page:$page,rows:$rows,productName:$productName,productCode:$productCode,productPrice:$productPrice,productQuantity:$productQuantity)&envelope=false";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->curlopt);

    echo  curl_exec($ch);
}
```

This my getproduct in my admincontroller but i can't figure out where is the limit there. thanks for the help :D in advance

Comment: Is there is limit 10 in your query?

Comment: actually i am not the one who build the query it was just turned over to me by the last programmer who just resigned and i don't know where i could changed the query

Comment: You can check that in "getproduct" controller in admin folder.

Comment: check the getproduct file, i'm sure there's a limit there.

Comment: thanks!!! i'll do it. i'm really new in web dev it's kind of hard for me

Comment: @Letme SuckitBaby : i pasted the getproduct above, i can't find the limit in thequery :'<